# Laravel 4 Class Function call error using $this

Tags: php, class, laravel, laravel-4

I want to use the functions addMenu and menu but I get this error:

```
Using $this when not in object context
```

Did I do something wrong? Or is there another way to call those functions?
My code:

```
class Documentation {
    protected $app;
    protected $menu = [];

    public function __construct(Application $app){
        $this->app = $app;
        $this->addMenu(["Hello world"]);

    }
    public static function addMenu($item){
        $this->menu[] = $item;
    }
    public static function menu(){
        return $this->menu;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you cannot use `$this` variable inside [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) context. In your case I would recommend you to change your function and get rid of the **static** keyword

```
class Documentation {
    protected $app;
    protected $menu = [];

    public function __construct(Application $app){
        $this->app = $app;
        $this->addMenu(["Hello world"]);
    }

    public function addMenu($item){
        $this->menu[] = $item;
    }

    public function menu(){
        return $this->menu;
    }
}
```